How to disabling certain UDP service ports?
I need assistance with disabling certain UDP service ports in a Yocto project layer or recipe. The services in question are:

ISAKMP
NAT-T-IKE
Zeroconf

Could you please provide guidance on how to disable these services within the Yocto project layer or recipe?

use iptables to block it

Can you give a example for iptables to disable those port .

welcome to serverfault.com where you can ask business related question in here. We want to ensure that you show us the relevant and related research you have done to solve it. We will support you by solving your already existing commands you tried

Are you using these technologies? If not, why do you have the corresponding services installed and running in the first place? If you don't use and don't need them, stop them and remove them, whatever is possible. This is called "reducing attack surface", nothing is better for the security of the service than absence of the service.

Use:
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --dport 111 -j DROP

or
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  --dport 111 -j REJECT

Replace 111 with the port number you want to block.

I need to be configure inside the meta layer for the disabling the listed above service. so is there any specific variables are avaiable in the yocto project? & I found out the all above UDP service are available in the meta-networking (open-embedded) Layer  but i'm not the getting the path to disable those service...

Any other methods are available to disable those ports apart from the iptables method?
